# Android Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Tags: java, android

Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for android exported when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined.
below  provided link to manifest file
added export to all activity then also showing same error
[this is my manifest]
(https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZeiwuZ9PKF47WURSlu9bNlGHNSP4Swb_sHGW--REPxc/edit?usp=sharing)